# How would I select this element to fill it out with jsnode selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to select a specific box in a .asp web form with multiple boxes. Here is a snippet of the code for the "Login Name" box.

```
<!--- user_name --->

<tr align="left" valign="top">

    <td nowrap class="left">
    <b>Login Name</b>
    </td>

    <td nowrap colspan="2">
    <input  type="text" 
            name="user_name" 
            value="" 
            size="60" 
            maxlength="32" 
            class="smalltext"
            onChange="javascript:CheckUserNameField();">
    </td>


</tr>
```

Here is what I tried for selecting it to enter text to it.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("input[name='user_name']")).sendKeys("asdfasd");
```

This is after my script opens the appropriate web page itself. The error i get is below.

```
(node:10904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such eleme
nt: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='u
ser_name']"}
```

Below is the copied selector for them from chrome, as well as the xpath's.

```
body > form > p > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input
body > form > p > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input
body > form > p > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input
body > form > p > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2) > input

/html/body/form/p/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input
/html/body/form/p/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input
/html/body/form/p/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input
/html/body/form/p/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input
```

I was unable to format any of those in a way that would select it, I'm certain this is user error at this point.

This has me pretty stumped. The other issue is there's multiple boxes I will need to select, and they all have the "class="smalltext", so I don't think I can select them by that. The only property that changes on each one is the "Name=____" field and the "onChange=______" field. As well as the bit in <------ -----> at the top and the bold name. Any help would be appreciated.

TL;DR: This .ASP form has 4 boxes I need to fill out, and I'm not sure how to select it with javascript selenium.

Comment: The `CSS` locator looks correct. It might be a synchronization issue or may be the field is inside an `iframe`. Did you try checking these cases?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, never got a notification! It doesn't appear to be within an iframe, the page it's on points only to "web.site/website/adduser.asp" So it is within a .asp form if that matters. What would a synchronization issue be?